# FriendlyId: undefined method `use_slug?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

I am creating a new environment besides production. I copied all the configurations from my production environment, changing what needed to be changed.

As it is the servers do start, but when I do a query I get this exception:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `use_slug?' for nil:NilClass):
  vendor/gems/friendly_id-2.3.4/lib/friendly_id/active_record2/finders.rb:65:in `slugged?'
  vendor/gems/friendly_id-2.3.4/lib/friendly_id/active_record2/finders.rb:43:in `finder_class'
  vendor/gems/friendly_id-2.3.4/lib/friendly_id/active_record2/finders.rb:37:in `finder'
  vendor/gems/friendly_id-2.3.4/lib/friendly_id/active_record2/finders.rb:32:in `method_missing'
  vendor/gems/friendly_id-2.3.4/lib/friendly_id/active_record2/slugged_model.rb:149:in `find_one'
  app/controllers/home_controller.rb:5:in `index'
```

The line in question does this:

```
@page = Page.find("home")
```

I am using FriendlyId 2.3.4, and Rails 2.3.4. The code is the same for the production environment, and it's working just fine there, so I'm not really sure on what's going on here...I could see that the line where the exception gets raised does

```
friendly_id_config.use_slug?
```

so for a reason I'm not aware of friendly_id_config is nil.

Thanks for any guidance on this problem

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround to this issue by loading the server using the production environment.
I was trying to use a 'preprod environment, and somehow FriendlyId didn't like that strange environment.
Load the app using RAILS_ENV=production and it worked fine.

Not a solution, but at least could move on...

Comment: I know that the extlib gem can cause troubles when used in combination with friendly_id